# How to check which textfield is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I want to change the value of an array based on the `textfield` that has been clicked. I have the following code:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        switch textField.tag {
        case 1:
            currentHospitals = hospitalsMCT
        case 2:
            currentHospitals = hospitalsSohar
        case 3:
            currentHospitals = hospitalsMusandam
        default:
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
```

but when I press alt and hover over the [textFieldShouldBeginEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619601-textfieldshouldbeginediting) it doesn't recognize the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

and are there better ways to detect which `textfield` is pressed?

Comment: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) this will call first

Comment: @UmaMadhavi thanks, trying it now

Comment: @UmaMadhavi is there any class I need to inherit? because I can't override that method as well

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi, have you delegate the text field? 

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
}

textfield.delegate = self;

Comment: @UmaMadhavi nevermind, it was newbie question, i had to inherit UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: @VigneshKumar i just did it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

just type that code in your view controller

// MARK: - Variables
var txtTemp: UITextField!

// MARK: - Delegate Methods
// MARK: UITextField

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    txtTemp = textField
}
```